# np.where multiple logical statements pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am aware there are many questions on the topic of chained logical operators using `np.where.`

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1
   A  B  C  D  E  F Postset
0  1  2  3  4  5  6     yes
1  1  2  3  4  5  6      no
2  1  2  3  4  5  6     yes

df2
   A  B  C  D  E  F Preset
0  1  2  3  4  5  6    yes
1  1  2  3  4  5  6    yes
2  1  2  3  4  5  6    yes
```

I want to compare the uniqueness of the rows in each dataframe. To do this, I need to check that all values are equal for **a number of selected columns.**

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions): if I am checking columns `a` `b` `c` `d` `e` `f` I can do:

```
np.where((df1.A != df2.A) | (df1.B != df2.B) | (df1.C != df2.C) | (df1.D != df2.D) | (df1.E != df2.E) | (df1.F != df2.F))
```

Which correctly gives:

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

i.e. the values in all columns are independently equal for both dataframes.

This is fine for a small dataframe, but my real dataframe has a high number of columns that I must check. The `np.where` condition is too long to write out with accuracy.

Instead, I would like to put my columns into a list:

```
columns_check_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

And use my `np.where` statement to perform my check over all columns automatically.

This obviously doesn't work, but its the type of form I am looking for. Something like:

```
check = np.where([df[column) != df[column] | for column in columns_check_list])
```

How can I achieve this?

Considerations:

- I have many columns
- The format of my data is fixed.
- The values within columns may contain either `strings` or `floats`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all values are `True` per row or [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) if at lest one value is `True` per row:

```
mask= ~(df1[columns_check_list] == df2[columns_check_list]).all(axis=1).values
print (mask)
[False False False]
```

Or more readable, thanks [IanS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677505/np-where-multiple-logical-statements-pandas/43677676?noredirect=1#comment74401087_43677676):

```
mask= (df1[columns_check_list] != df2[columns_check_list]).any(axis=1).values
print (mask)
[False False False]
```

Is also possible compare `numpy array`s:

```
mask= (df1[columns_check_list].values != df2[columns_check_list].values).any(axis=1)
print (mask)
[False False False]
```

Comment: Or `(df1[columns_check_list] != df2[columns_check_list]).any(axis=1)` which would be more human-readable?

Comment: Why do I always forget `all` and `any`. These are probably better suited in this case because they can short-circuit (they only process the row as long as there wasn't a difference yet) the operation.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. I completely forgot about `np.any` and `np.all`. It works great. Oh, and congratulations on 100k too! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html)s [`reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce) method on the values of the comparison:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.logical_or.reduce((df1 != df2).values, axis=1)  # along rows
array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)               # each value represents a row
```

You might need to exclude columns either before doing the comparison:

```
(df1[include_columns_list] != df2[include_columns_list]).values
```

or after:

```
(df1 != df2)[include_columns_list].values
```

Besides `np.logical_or` there's also a [`np.bitwise_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html) but if your dealing with booleans (and the comparison returns an array of booleans) these are equivalent.

Comment: `np.logical_or.reduce((df1 != df2)[columns_list].values, axis=1)`  ?