# Pandas: Select Rows with condition for several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using this to conditionally select rows of `column`:

`X.loc[data['column'] == 1]`

But I want to expand this condition to several columns. These columns have something in common: They contain a same string. So actually I have a `column1`, a `column2`, ... , `column100` etc. and this condition should apply to all of these columns. Actually something like this (wildcard):

`X.loc[data['column*'] == 1]`

These conditions should be linked with `OR`. Any chance to do this easily?

Comment: Have a look at`numpy.any()`  Two questions I asked very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677505/np-where-multiple-logical-statements-pandas and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647710/compare-boolean-row-values-across-multiple-columns-in-pandas-using-np-where

Comment: For a list of your columns you want to test against `col_list`, Try `X.loc[(X[col_list] == 1).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: @chuckm the `.loc` is not needed

Comment: @MaartenFabré Thanks for the info, updated and credited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## test Dataframe

```
    col0 col1 col2
0   1    1    2
1   1    1    1
2   2    2    2
```

make a new dataframe with the test for all columns

```
result_s = d.concat((df['col%i'%i] == 1 for i in range(3)), axis=1).all(axis=1)
```

results in

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

if you do `df[result_s]` you get

```
    col0 col1 col2
1   1    1    1
```

this selects the rows where all columns are `==1` If one of the is enough, change the `.all()` to `.any`

```
    col0 col1 col2
0   1    1    2
1   1    1    1
```

Comment: Looks nice :) But this is not working generally, e.g. if these columns are named as ``columnOne``, ``columnTwo`` etc.

Comment: if you have a list of the columns, `df[(df[selected_columns]==1).any(axis=1)]` can work too and be more efficient

Comment: @scientiaetveritas `df['col%i'%i] == 1 for i in range(3)` is just a method to select the columns, depending on how they look this might need modification. You will need to provide more information in your question to make this clear

Answer (score 7):

For some dataframe `X`

```
   p A  p B  p C
0    0    0    0
1    0    0    0
2    0    0    1
3    0    0    0
4    0    0    0
5    0    0    0
6    1    0    0
```

If you can set up the names of the columns you want to test for in `col_list`

```
col_list = X.columns
```

You can then use `np.any()` to test with or between each:

```
X.loc[(X[col_list] == 1).any(axis=1)]
```

Which gives you:

```
   p A  p B  p C
2    0    0    1
6    1    0    0
```

Informed you don't need `loc` and will still get the same answer, credit to @MaartynFabre for the info

```
X[(X[col_list] == 1).any(axis=1)]

   p A  p B  p C
2    0    0    1
6    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Put each comparison in brackets and combine them with logical operators:

```
pd.DataFrame(X).loc[(data['col1']==23) & (data['col2']==42)] # and
pd.DataFrame(X).loc[(data['col1']==23) | (data['col2']==42)] # or
```

Comment: Thanks :) But I can't do this for hundreds of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to consider:

```
df
   col0  col1  col2
0     1     1     2
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2

df.loc[df['col0'] == 1, [x for x in df.columns if x == 'col0']]
   col0
0     1
1     1
```

You can use list comprehension to find the columns you're looking for.