# Find values in numpy array space-efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a copy of my numpy array that contains only certain values. This is the code I was using:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
query_val = 5
B = (A == query_val) * np.array(query_val, dtype=np.uint16)
```

... which does exactly what I want.

Now, I'd like query_val to be more than just one value. The answer here:  [Numpy where function multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions) suggests using a logical and operation, but that's very space inefficient because you use == several times, creating multiple intermediate results.

In my case, that means I don't have enough RAM to do it. Is there a way to do this properly in native numpy with minimal space overhead?

Comment: Could there be duplicates in `A`?

Comment: Yes, there will be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def mask_in(a, b):
    idx = np.searchsorted(b,a)
    idx[idx==b.size] = 0
    return np.where(b[idx]==a, a,0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [356]: a
Out[356]: 
array([[5, 1, 4],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [2, 4, 9]])

In [357]: b
Out[357]: array([2, 4, 5])

In [358]: mask_in(a,b)
Out[358]: 
array([[5, 0, 4],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [2, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Though, if I see this right, this needs to allocate many times the space of the full-size array (1. a, 2. idx, 3. idx==b.size, 4. b[idx], 5. b[idx]==a, 6. np.where(...)) while my code needs 2 full-size allocations.

Comment: @fns  We can easily write back to the results to the input array with the mask `b[idx]==a` if you don't want a copy as output. So, do you want a copy or write back?

Comment: @fns Other than that, we have have memory occupancy for `idx` and `b[idx]`. Since, we have duplicates in `a`, there won't be an easy solution to it. If memory is super critical for you, I think you should stick to a loopy solution.