# Convert a range of values to 0

Tags: python, numpy

How can i go about converting a range of values inside a list(numpy array) of list to one number and leave all other numbers as they were,
I tried the

```
np.where(array!= range(-1024,0),array,0))
```

but this one gives me an error,any suggestions on how i may do so,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isin` i.e

```
array = np.array([-150,105,250,-520,-1024,-1050])

np.where( ~np.isin(array, np.arange(-1024,0)) , array, 0)

array([    0,   105,   250,     0,     0, -1050])
```

Comment: Just an additional note, if your `np.__version__` is smaller than `1.13`, you won't have `np.isin` but you'll get the same result using `np.in1d`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
np.where(np.logical_and(a>=-1024 , a<=0),0,a)
```

This will check if the element of a is in the range [-1024,0] and make it 0 else leave it unchanged.

You can also refer this answer [Numpy where function multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple list comprehension:

```
[e if e not in range(-1024,0) else 0 for e in array]
```

Or equivalently (more straightforward):

```
[0 if e in range(-1024,0) else e for e in array]
```

Edit: It may be argued that list-based answer is easier to read, but it is drastically slower than the numpy-based ones (think about `3.76 µs` vs `453 µs`!) So I'd stick with the numpy answers.

Comment: lists & list comprehension are slow as compared to numpy arrays

Comment: @UmangGupta I just tested the speed and you are so right! I'll include this information in my edit. Thanks.