# Python: Maintain multiple columns with np.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to maintain multiple columns at once using `np.where`?
usually, one column is maintained with `np.where`, so my coding would look like this:

```py
df['col1'] = np.where(df[df.condition == 'yes'],'sth', '')
df['col2'] = np.where(df[df.condition == 'yes'], 50.00, 0.0)
```

But caused by the fact that I test for the same condition twice, I was wondering, if I can pass 2 columns and fill them both in one run.

I tried this:

```py
df['col1','col2'] = np.where(df[df.condition == 'yes'],['sth',50.00], ['',0.0])
```

But it does not work. Is there a way to realize this?

Comment: What do you mean by "maintain multiple columns at once"? Can you show a sample of the data you have and the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy where function multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions)

Comment: @jezrael, I'm struggling to understand this question. If you understand it, would mind editing the question? I can see this confusing many users, not just me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need reshape boolean mask to `(N x 1)`:

```
m = df.condition == 'yes'
df[['col1','col2']] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m[:, None], ['sth',50.00], ['',0.0]))
```

Only disadvatage of solution is if different types of values in `list`s - numeric with `string`s - then `numpy.where` both output columns convert to `string`s.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                     'condition':['yes'] * 3 + ['no'] * 3})

print (df)
   A condition
0  a       yes
1  b       yes
2  c       yes
3  d        no
4  e        no
5  f        no

m = df.condition == 'yes'
df[['col1','col2']] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m[:, None], ['sth',50.00], ['',0.0]))
print (df)
   A condition col1  col2
0  a       yes  sth  50.0
1  b       yes  sth  50.0
2  c       yes  sth  50.0
3  d        no        0.0
4  e        no        0.0
5  f        no        0.0

print (df.applymap(type))
               A      condition           col1           col2
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
3  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
4  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
5  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

EDIT: I test it with `NaN`s values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdefghi'),
                     'condition':['yes'] * 3 + ['no'] * 3 + [np.nan] * 3})

m = df.condition == 'yes'
df[['col1','col2']] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m[:, None], ['sth',50.00], ['',0.0]))
print (df)
   A condition col1  col2
0  a       yes  sth  50.0
1  b       yes  sth  50.0
2  c       yes  sth  50.0
3  d        no        0.0
4  e        no        0.0
5  f        no        0.0
6  g       NaN        0.0
7  h       NaN        0.0
8  i       NaN        0.0
```

Comment: thank you, this almost works. Any idea, why it does not work for the last 6 rows? col1 and col2 both contain nan within these last rows, all other rows have valid content.

Comment: @MaMo - hmmm, it seems there is problem need another condition for exclude `NaNs`.

Comment: @MaMo - I add sample to answer with `NaN`s and it working nice. Can you test it? Or I dont understand what you need?

Comment: I get `NaN`s in col1 and col2 for last few rows, not in the condition column. I so not know the reason because there is nothing special about those rows or the condition column.

Comment: @MaMo - Without data hard to know, are data confidental?

Comment: yes, they are, but problem solved. It has been my mistake, the df I used has been a subset of another df so the indexing has been the problem. Added `df.reset_index()` before executing the `np.where`-Coding and voilà :) Thanks again!