# update multiple columns of pandas dataframe using np.where or loc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

We have a dataframe:

```
data = [['A1', 'B1'], ['A2', 'B2', 1, 2], ['A3', 'B3', 3, 4], ['A4', 'B4']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

which looks like this

```
A  | B  | C   | D
-------------------
A1 | B1 | NaN | NaN
A2 | B2 | 1   | 2
A3 | B3 | 3   | 4
A4 | B4 | Nan | NaN
-------------------
```

for columns `C` and `D`, they will both be populated or both be `NaN` (there wont be a scenario where `C` is `NaN` and `D` will have values or vice versa)

My goal is to transform the dataframe to look like this:

```
A  | B  | C   | D
-------------------
A1 | B1 | NaN | NaN
1  | 2  | 1   | 2
3  | 4  | 3   | 4
A4 | B4 | Nan | NaN
-------------------
```

I have tried

```
df.loc[df['C'].notna(), ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[df['C'].notna(), ['C', 'D']]
# the above just assigns back NaN values instead of 1,2,3,4
```

and

```
m = df['C'].notna()
df[['A', 'B']] = np.where(m, df[['C', 'D']], df[['A', 'B']])
# the above errors with operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,2) (4,2) 
df[['X', 'Y']] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, df[['C', 'D']]), df[['A', 'B']])
# the above errors with ValueError: either both or neither of X and Y should be given
```

I have looked into this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447233/python-maintain-multiple-columns-with-np-where), and tried some ways to convert `df[['C', 'D']]` as lists and assign it back as a new dataframe but I have still not been able to make it work.

I know I can assign the columns (A-C, B-D) individually but I am dealing with a large number of such pairs and want to avoid looping through them. Is there a clean way to do this operation in a single pass?

using pandas version 0.25.3.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try retrieving values to assign, namely:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A1', 'B1'], ['A2', 'B2', 1, 2], ['A3', 'B3', 3, 4], ['A4', 'B4']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C','D'])

df.loc[df['C'].notna(), ['A','B']] = df.loc[df['C'].notna(), ['C','D']].to_numpy()

df

    A   B    C    D
0  A1  B1  NaN  NaN
1   1   2  1.0  2.0
2   3   4  3.0  4.0
3  A4  B4  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `pandas.loc[...]`:

```py
df.loc[~df['C'].isna(), 'A']=df.loc[~df['C'].isna(), 'C']
df.loc[~df['D'].isna(), 'B']=df.loc[~df['D'].isna(), 'D']
```

Using `np.where(...)`:

```py
import numpy as np

df[['A', 'B']]=np.where(df['C'].notna().to_numpy().reshape(-1,1), df[['C', 'D']], df[['A', 'B']])
```

Output:

```py
    A   B    C    D
0  A1  B1  NaN  NaN
1   1   2  1.0  2.0
2   3   4  3.0  4.0
3  A4  B4  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Could you please explain the `.to_numpy().reshape(-1.1)` part for me.