# How can I use numpy where function with more than one condition.(I must use where function)

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 numpy array and I want to know at each index which one is bigger.(all of the data are numbers)

```
arm1_data=dataset[:,34]
arm2_data=dataset[:,35]
arm3_data=dataset[:,36]
arm4_data=dataset[:,37]
```

what should I do? (I saw this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions) but it doesn't work for me)

Comment: bigger with respect to what? element wise? norm? you should explain more and give a simple example

Comment: all of the data are numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `np.argmax` instead:

```
idx = np.argmax(dataset[:, 34:38], axis=1)
```

this would give you an index per row, with 0 being 34, 1 being 35, ...