# tf.where with multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Akin to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions), given an array `dists`, one can filter out elements following multiple conditions using `np.where` and `&`, e.g.
`dists[np.where((dists >= r) & (dists**2. <= 100))]`

Is there an equivalent way to input more than one condition in `tf.where`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.math.logical_and` can be used to do element-wise and operation in tensorflow. To get specified elements out of a tensor by their indices, use `tf.gather_nd`.

Example codes:

```
@tf.function
def eg_func(x,a,b):
  return tf.gather_nd(x,tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(x > a,x < b)))

x=tf.reshape(tf.range(3*3),[3,3])
print(x)
print(eg_func(x,2,7))
```

Expected outputs:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 4 5 6], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```