# Using np.where with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Why does the first line work but not the second?

ok:

```
data_frame['C'] = np.where(np.logical_and(np.greater_equal(data_frame['A'],1), np.not_equal(data_frame['B'],0)), 'OK', '-'  )
```

not ok:

```
data_frame['C'] = np.where(data_frame['A']== 1 & data_frame['B']!=0, 'OK', '-')
```

> TypeError: Cannot perform `rand_` with a dtyped `[float64]` array and scalar of type `[bool]]`

Answer (score 2):

It's just the order of operations not being correct if you don't have parens/brackets in the appropriate places. This should work in place of your 2nd variant:

```
np.where((data_frame['A'] == 1) & 
         (data_frame['B'] != 0), 'OK', '-')
```

So the comparison operations -- `==`, `!=` -- execute before the bitwise one: `&`.

Edit: this other SO answer explains the order-of-operations thing in more detail -- under the "UPDATE" heading -- in case you need/want that level of explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57922782/42346