# How to extract data point from two numpy arrays based on two conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays; x, y. I want to be able to extract the value of x that is closest to 1 that also has a y value greater than 0.96 and the get the index of that value.

```
x = [0.5, 0.8, 0.99, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.91, 1.01, 10, 20]
y = [0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.85]
```

In this case the x value would be 1.01 because it is closest to 1 and has a y value of 0.99.

Ideal result would be:

```
idx = 7
```

I know how to find the point nearest to 1 and how to get the index of it but I don't know how to add the second condition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions

Comment: What if there were two 1.01 values with y > 0.96 in the x list.  Which y would you choose?

Answer (score 0):

This code also works when there are multiple indexes satisfying the condition.

```
import numpy as np

x = [0.5, 0.8, 0.99, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.91, 1.01, 10, 20]
y = [0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.85]
# differences
first_check = np.abs(np.array(x) - 1)
# extracting index of the value that x is closest to 1
# (indexes in case there are two or more values that are closest to 1)
indexes = np.where(first_check == np.min(first_check))[0]

indexes = [index for index in indexes if y[index] > 0.96]

print(indexes)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.argsort(abs(x - 1))` to sort the indices according to the closest value to `1`. Then, grab the first `y` index that satisfies `y > 0.96` using `np.where`.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.5, 0.8, 0.99, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.91, 1.01, 10, 20])
y = np.array([0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.85])

closest_inds = np.argsort(abs(x - 1))
idx = closest_inds[np.where(y[closest_inds] > 0.96)][0]
```

This would give:

```
idx = 7
```

For short arrays (shorter than, say 10k elements), the above solution would be slow because there is no `findfirst` in numpy till the moment. Look at [this long awaited feature](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2269) request.

So, in this case, the following loop would be much faster and will give same result:

```
for i in closest_inds:
    if y[i] > 0.96:
        idx = i
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on multiple conditions and lists.

```
x = [0.5, 0.8, 0.99, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.91, 1.01, 10, 20]

y = [0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.85]


condition1 = 1.0
condition2 = 0.96


def convert(*args):
    """
    Returns a list of tuples generated from multiple lists and tuples
    """
    for x in args:
        if not isinstance(x, list) and not isinstance(x, tuple):
            return []

    size = float("inf")
    
    for x in args:
        size = min(size, len(x)) 
    result = []
    for i in range(size):
        result.append(tuple([x[i] for x in args]))
    print(result)
    return result

result = convert(x, y)

closest = min([tpl for tpl in result if tpl[0] >= condition1 and tpl[1] > condition2], key=lambda x: x[1])

index = result.index(closest)

print(f'The index of the closest numbers of x-list to 1 and y-list to 0.96 is {index}')
```

**Output**

```
[(0.5, 0.7), (0.8, 0.75), (0.99, 0.8), (0.8, 0.85), (0.85, 0.9), (0.9, 0.95), (0.91, 0.99), (1.01, 0.99), (10, 0.99), (20, 0.85)]
The index of the closest numbers is 7
```

Comment: The OP asked for such an operation on **numpy arrays**.