# How to use np.where for more than one values?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of size (1318, 1816), I would like to replace values other than that 23,43, and 64 to zero. I have tried `np.where`, but returns an array full of zero. can anyone help me to correct the following code:

```
arr=np.array(img)
labels=[23,43,64]
arr_masked= np.where(arr!=labels,0,arr)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy where function multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

```
arr_masked= np.where(np.isin(arr, labels), arr, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve my question:

```
arr_masked= np.where((arr != 23)*(arr != 43)*(arr != 64) , 0, arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below using **np.isin** & **np.where**

```
import numpy as np

img = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
labels = [2,5]

print(np.where(np.isin(img,labels),1,img))
```

Output:

```
[1 1 3 4 1]
```